# how to detect object type in grails

Tags: grails, grails-domain-class

i have a method who receives a object as a param.

It is possible to check if the object is an instance of my domain classes?

```
def assignDocument(Document document, def objectClass){
   // objectClass is a object of my domain classes?
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear whether `objectClass` is a domain class *instance* or a `Class` instance. If it's a domain class instance you can check this like so:

```
   if (domainInstance.class in grailsApplication.domainClasses.clazz) {
     println "domainInstance is a domain instance"
   }
```

If you want to check whether a `Class` instance is the type of one of your domain classes, use this:

```
   if (domainType in grailsApplication.domainClasses.clazz) {
     println "domainType is a domain Class"
   }
```